# Firebase exception with long Strings on Android

Tags: android, firebase

I want to save an image to Firebase as a String. For this I encode it as a Base64 String.

Everything works fine for smaller images (eg a 15128 characters String is ok) but for larger ones I get an exception.

Here's the stack trace, this image is 34807 characters long encoded after Base64 encoding:

```
07-10 09:45:38.414      879-896/com.firebase.androidchat       E/DefaultRunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop. Please report to support@firebase.com
        java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=34807; regionStart=32768; regionLength=16384
        at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
        at com.firebase.client.utilities.Utilities.splitIntoFrames(Utilities.java:85)
        at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.send(WebsocketConnection.java:159)
        at com.firebase.client.realtime.Connection.sendData(Connection.java:200)
        at com.firebase.client.realtime.Connection.sendRequest(Connection.java:89)
        at com.firebase.client.core.PersistentConnection.sendAction(PersistentConnection.java:744)
        at com.firebase.client.core.PersistentConnection.sendPut(PersistentConnection.java:697)
        at com.firebase.client.core.PersistentConnection.putInternal(PersistentConnection.java:684)
        at com.firebase.client.core.PersistentConnection.put(PersistentConnection.java:307)
        at com.firebase.client.core.PersistentConnection.put(PersistentConnection.java:303)
        at com.firebase.client.core.Repo.setValue(Repo.java:215)
        at com.firebase.client.Firebase$1.run(Firebase.java:427)
```

Am I hitting the maximum allowed Firebase String size or is it a bug in the Android SDK? any work-around?

Comment: seems like a bug but in firebase client library in `com.firebase.client.utilities.Utilities.splitIntoFrames`

Comment: Firebase dev here.  I can confirm this is a bug in the Android SDK.  We do have a max string size at 10mb, but what you're hitting is just a bug.  We should be able to get a fixed version out early next week.  Sorry for the inconvenience!

If you're desperate for a workaround, you could look into using our REST API (https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html) to upload the images for the time being.

Comment: Thanks! I'll survive until next week ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase dev here. The latest release of the SDK (v1.0.2) should fix this issue. Can you give it a try and let me know if it's resolved?

https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

This is just issue of older version of firebase database dependency of gradle file just update it with latest version...
**THAT'S IT**

Comment: Yeah, this happened with literally the first ever release they had on Android :D