# Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0). Please report to support@firebase.com

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching

I have a problem with offline capabilities. 
I turn on offline feature in my project with firebase.
Everything is fine until i close app completely and reopen it. It made crash.

This is log

```
05-23 07:44:58.407 7286-7328/com.iantsu.projectm E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafg.zzg(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafa, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahu)' on a null object reference
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafc.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafc.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafc.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.IPersistentConnectionImpl$3.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzi$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at alx.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:181)
at amb.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:321)
at akf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:403)
at ajt.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:82)
at ajt.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:14087)
at akw.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:320)
at alf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:7310)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-23 07:44:59.655 7286-7328/com.iantsu.projectm E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafg.zzg(com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafa, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahu)' on a null object reference
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafc.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafc.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafc.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.IPersistentConnectionImpl$3.onDisconnect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.idl.zzi$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at alx.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:181)
at amb.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:321)
at akf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:403)
at ajt.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:82)
at ajt.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:14087)
at akw.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:320)
at alf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:7310)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also use Glide to cache image too. Is that make crash ? 
I used Firebase before in the same project (but older version) but it did not happen.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Did you already report this to support@firebase.com as the error stated?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567776/firebase-exception-with-long-strings-on-android

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208878/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0-related-to-persistence-and-querie